# PostgreSql PHP query

Tags: php

Integrante do meu grupo que manja em BD nos deixou com problema. Quando executo o seguinte comando:

Query:

```
$query = "SELECT c.destino, c.origem, cc.data, cc.informacoes FROM " . $this -> name_entity . "  c, " . $this -> name_entity . "_tres cc where c.id_" . $this -> name_entity . " = cc.id_ " . $this -> name_entity;
```

Esta retornando o erro:

> erro: Warning: pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "carona" LINE 1: ... carona c, carona_tres cc where c.id_carona = cc.id_ carona ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\carona-ecologica\model\repositorio\RepositorioEntidade.php

Qual sintaxe para essa query que não estou conseguindo desenvolver?

help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali no final do seu código, existe um espaço entre id_ e carona

```
 cc.id_ " . $this
```

Código correto:

```
 cc.id_" . $this
```

Comment: Obg! funcionou.